# A code sample inside of an italicized block should not be italicized

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-rendering, code

I wrote the following comment [on a post on Meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252948/delete-own-question-which-is-a-down-vote-magnet#252948):

> *Not the `language-lawyer` tag again...*

The comment shows up as italicized (which it should), but the code inside of the italicized comment *should not be* italicized.

After all, it *is* code.

This seems to be unintended behavior for the Markdown parser.

Comment: *Not the `language-lawyer` tag again...*

Comment: I was tempted to tag this post with the `language-lawyer` tag; but I felt like that would be too meta.

Comment: Yeah, meta meta is the limit. Meta meta meta is off topic. LOL

Comment: Anyway, I'm really surprised nobody spotted or reported this before usually people catch those things much faster than, how much time? 5 years? :)

Comment: What if you want to emphasize something in code with italics?

Comment: @Emracool this shouldn't be possible in my opinion, code should be plain.

Comment: I saw a post once with a C code block (~20 lines)  italicized... looks real strange (+ prettify didn't kick in IIRC). `<i> [empty line] [normal 4-space-indented code] </i>`.

Comment: Considering you could simply unitalicize *before the* `code` *then italicize after*, it seems better to leave both options available than to limit it artificially

Answer (score 5):

Why not? Other formatting is applied to the inside of code blocks, and in at least some cases it's desired behavior (e.g. linking to documentation for a function). It seems inconsistent to just block italics, it's not that hard to stop and restart the formatting, and it's good to have the option when you need it.

Comment: Lots of editors italicize parts of code anyway.

Comment: @kevin - Agree with this. I've actually used bold formatting to emphasize certain bits of code.